# Доступ к переменным при вызове функций извне - C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, большое спасибо всем, кто отвечает!

Вот и я сам добрался до момента, когда не могу разобраться, прошу вашей помощи. Имеется такой код:
в двух словах, приложение подключается к биржевой программе, которая по средствам RTD interface в реальном времени отдает данные о котировках и их обновлении, проблема как раз в обновлении.

Извне вызывается моя функция     `UpdateNotify()` класса     `RtdUpdate`.

1. Как **правильно** построить логику передачи управления внутри приложения, при условии вызова одной из функций извне?
2. В каком месте следует передавать выполнение кода в новый поток при том же условии (вызов одной из функций извне)?
3. Что стоит учесть при написании функций, которые вызываются извне?

Имеется такой код:

```
 <code>
 public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
    //создаем переменную типа RtdClient
    RtdClient rtdClient;
    //создаем переменную типа updateNotification
    RtdUpdate rtdUpdate;
    //конструктор Form1
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tosClassId = new Guid(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\myapp.COMApp.1\CLSID\", "", null).ToString());
        rtdClient = new RtdClient(tosClassId, this);
        //отправляем ссылку на наш клиент, для обновлений
        rtdUpdate = new RtdUpdate(ref rtdClient);
        //подписываем наш клиент на обновления
        rtdClient.StartListenUpdate(ref rtdUpdate);
    }

    //функция, обновляет значения в массивах, если пришло update
    public void UpdateOnePrice(object _inputSendDataToThread)
    {
        /* тут код который анализирует обновление */
    }

    //класс реализует RtdClient
    public class RtdClient
    {
        Form1 form;
        Type rtd;
        IRtdServer server;


        public RtdClient(Guid _serverId, Form1 _form)
        {
            form = _form;
            rtd = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(_serverId);
            server = (IRtdServer)Activator.CreateInstance(rtd);
        }

        public void StartListenUpdate(ref RtdUpdate _rtdUpdate)
        {
            server.ServerStart(_rtdUpdate);
        }

        public void updateData()
        {
            try
            {
                var refresh = server.RefreshData(1);

                if (refresh.Length > 0)
                {
                    sendDataToThread send = new sendDataToThread();
                    send.data[0, 0] = refresh[0, 0];
                    send.data[1, 0] = refresh[1, 0];
                    form.UpdateOnePrice(send);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: Log exception
                MessageBox.Show("error:" + ex);
            }
        }

    }


    public class RtdUpdate : IRTDUpdateEvent
    {
        RtdClient rtdClient = null;
        ThreadManager threadManager;

        public delegate void MethodContainer();

        public RtdUpdate(ref RtdClient _rtdClient)
        {
            rtdClient = _rtdClient;
            threadManager = new ThreadManager();
        }


        public void UpdateNotify()
        {
            //узнаем номер свободного потока
            int numThread = -1;
            while (numThread < 0)
            {
                numThread = threadManager.FreeThreadPlz();
            }
            //запускаем обновление в свободном потоке
            threadManager.threads[numThread] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rtdClient.updateData));
            threadManager.threads[numThread].Start();
        }
    }

    //класс для того, чтобы описать, то что передаем в новый поток
    public class sendDataToThread
    {
        public object[,] data = new object[2, 1];
    }

    //класс который реализует управление потоками
    public class ThreadManager
    {
        //кол-во разрешенных потоков 
        int threadCount = 10;

        //массив с рабочими потоками
        public Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];

        //какой поток сейчас свободен
        public int FreeThread = 0;

        //конструктор
        public ThreadManager()
        {
            Array.Resize(ref threads, threadCount);
        }

        public int FreeThreadPlz()
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!threads[i].IsAlive)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            /*
               LOG TO all BUSY THREAD 
             */

            return -1;
        }
    }
    //ниже описание интерфейсов
    [ComImport, TypeLibType((short)0x1040), Guid("EC0E6191-DB51-11D3-8F3E-00C04F3651B8")]
    public interface IRtdServer
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(10)]
        int ServerStart([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IRTDUpdateEvent callback);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(11)]
        object ConnectData([In] int topicId, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] ref object[] parameters, [In, Out] ref bool newValue);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(12)]
        object[,] RefreshData([In, Out] ref int topicCount);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(13)]
        void DisconnectData([In] int topicId);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(14)]
        int Heartbeat();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(15)]
        void ServerTerminate();
    }

    //[ComImport, TypeLibType((short)0x1040), Guid("A43788C1-D91B-11D3-8F39-00C04F3651B8")]
    public interface IRTDUpdateEvent
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(10), PreserveSig]
        void UpdateNotify();

        /*
        [DispId(11)]
        int HeartbeatInterval
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(11)]
            get;
            [param: In]
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(11)]
            set;
        }
        */

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(12)]
        void Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Окей. Вам придётся сообщить нам в точности, что это за «исключение, какой-то там COM объект, бла, бла, бла». Потому что это сообщение пытается донести до вас (ну и до нас тоже), что же не так.

Comment: Чтобы биржевая программа вызвала вашу функцию `UpdateNotify()`, она сначала должна создать экземпляр класса `RtdUpdate`, передав в него экземпляр `RtdClient`. Попробуйте сделать класс `RtdUpdate` статичным или синглтоном.

Comment: @iRumba бирже не надо ничего создавать - экземпляр класса `RtdUpdate` передается как параметр метода `ServerStart` в конструкторе.

Comment: Если передается экземпляр класса RtdUpdate, то должен передаваться и RtdClient в его составе.

Comment: @iRumba и что из этого следует?

Comment: Что создавать IRtdServer достаточно один раз, после чего использовать уже созданный. Для этого нужно  проверять поле server на null и если оно null, создавать, если нет то не создавать )

Comment: @VladD Дело в том, что в дальнейших моих поисках решения, ошибка "бла, бла, бла" исчезла, но появилась новая, приложение зависает, совершенно не могу определить место на котором зависает, потому что инициализация проходит успешно, все классы создаются, первоначальная информация запрашивается по принудительному обращению к RTD server, отправляя в этот же момент номер (число типа int), как бы подписываясь на обновления, присваивая номер этой цене. Так вот в дальнейшем приложение зависает, выскакивает ошибка якобы все висит уже 60сек, у вас кодкривожоп.

Comment: @K.Oleg: Хм. Тогда внесите эту информацию в вопрос, мало кто дочитает до 7-го комментария.

Comment: @iRumba  проверку переменной   server на null, убрал из кода найденного в internet, дабы понимать в какой момент эта переменная может иметь значение null, с условием того, что в конструкторе класса ей присваивается значение. В общем то в этом и был первоначальный вопрос, как такое может быть, что я значение присваиваю, а потом при вызове функции    UpdateNotify() значение переменной пустое, как будто вызывает другой экземпляр класса    RtdUpdate в котором действительно переменная server=null.

Comment: @VladD хорошо, но первоначальный вопрос звучит примерно так: при написании функции которая будет вызываться из вне, требуется ли какое-либо специальное ее объявление, и что требуется учесть в написании такой функции.

Comment: @K.Oleg: Это да, но в такой формулировке («напишите полный список того, что нужно учесть») никто не возьмётся отвечать. Вариант «у меня такая вот ошибка, что я делаю не так?» выглядит намного легче.

Comment: @VladD нужно новый вопрос создавать? или можно в этом все писать?

Comment: @K.Oleg: Я думаю, стоит отредактировать этот вопрос.

Comment: @VladD отредактировал, спасибо

Comment: я не сильно шарю в ком объектах, но могу предположить, что объекты передаются не по ссылкам, а по значению. Сериализуются. А приватные поля таким образом не передаются, кажется.

Comment: @iRumba: Насколько мне помнится, там сложнее. Там в некоторых случаях создаётся proxy-объект, который перенаправляет все вызовы «настоящему» объекту. (Например, если у оригинального объекта single-threaded apartment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал Publish/Subscribe архитектуру для сообщения между потоками и Inversion of Control для управления жизненным циклом потоков.

Publish/Subscribe это некая шина данных внутри приложения, через которую потоки общаются между собой.

В IoC контейнере в отдельном потоке создаём объект, который работает с COM объектом. Объект через делегат получает сообщение, на его базе создаёт своё внутренне сообщение которое отдаёт в шину данных.

Другие потоки (интерфейс(viewmodel) или другие обработчики) заранее подписаны на сообщения в этой шине данных, получают сообщения и используют по своему усмотрению.

Не сложные к освоению Publish/Subscribe и Ioc. 
Nuget:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents
IoC контейнер NuGet:Unity 4.0.1

Comment: Да причем тут Publish/Subscribe? У автора проблема в другом. Вы приглядитесь как он свободный поток запрашивает...

Comment: Возможно офтоп, я не решаю конкретную задачу, но предлагаю автору изучить эти 2 техники и переписать код, чем вам не нравиться этот подход?

Comment: Автор *уже* нахватался идей, которые не смог понять - и потому у него сейчас программа зависает. А вы ему предлагаете *еще одну* непонятную идею. Неужели вы и правда думаете, что если он перепишет код используя pubsub, он выкинет свой ThreadManager? Нет, не выкинет - и будет у него две проблемы вместо одной.

Comment: Возможно автор не сможет возможно сможет, но я хотя бы попытался предложить подход, если до сих пор этот вопрос помечен "без ответа".